# UNO error: Binary URP bridge disposed during call

Tags: python, python-3.x, archlinux, uno

I am trying to test **Python UNO api** with LibreOffice and It is producing a strange error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 16, in <module>
__main__.RuntimeException: Binary URP bridge disposed during call

shell returned 1
```

Below is my Code:

```
import socket
import uno
localContext = uno.getComponentContext()
resolver = localContext.ServiceManager.createInstanceWithContext(
                                   "com.sun.star.bridge.UnoUrlResolver", localContext )
ctx = resolver.resolve( "uno:socket,host=localhost,port=2002;urp;StarOffice.ComponentContext" )
smgr = ctx.ServiceManager
desktop = smgr.createInstanceWithContext("com.sun.star.frame.Desktop",ctx) //this line is generating error
model = desktop.getCurrentComponent()
text = model.Text
cursor = text.createTextCursor()
text.insertString( cursor, "Hello World", 0 )
ctx.ServiceManager
```

As I mentioned in code, this line is generating error
*smgr.createInstanceWithContext("com.sun.star.frame.Desktop",ctx)*

I am trying to build it upon ARCH LINUX with KDE environment using python3.

Comment: This error means that LibreOffice crashed or the pyuno bridge crashed. You can see how we use pyuno for connections internally in the Libreoffice code in https://cgit.freedesktop.org/libreoffice/core/tree/uitest/libreoffice/connection.py

Comment: Did you use both the libreoffice and python executables both packaged from the same version of libreoffice?  (We had that error when the libreoffice was newer and we pointed to a python from an older version of libreoffice)